Any decomposition of inverse of nonnegative diagonal matrix times a PSD matrix plus lambda times Identity?
I generally have to solve the following system:
$$
(DA + \lambda I)^{-1} v
$$
where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries, $A$ a symmetric, positive semi-definite (PSD) matrix, $I$ is the identity matrix, $\lambda > 0$, and $v$ a vector.
I have to solve this for many different input $D$ so wondering if anyone knows a way I could decompose this equation, so that I could only do one expensive factorization or inverse up front, and just update the result for different $D$ with a simpler computation.
E.g., I was hoping there may be something like taking the eigendecomposition of A and from there for each new D a simple update formula, or something like the rank one inverse update formula (Sherman-Morrison) - but in this case the change is just changing the diagonal matrix multiplier, $D$.
Does anyone know of any way?

Hopefully someone can show I'm wrong but I think what you're trying to do is not possible.
It may be easier to see why your formula is problematic if you first write
$$
(DA + \lambda I )^{-1} = (A + \lambda D^{-1})^{-1}D^{-1}
$$
The LHS has the same complexity as the RHS because you've only added the step of inverting D which is diagonal so that's easy.  The complexity of the RHS is dominated by computing $(A + \lambda D^{-1})^{-1}$.  Now consider the two techniques you suggested.
The Woodbury-Matrix identity (the generalized Sherman-Morrison formula) doesn't help you because it just gives
$$
(A + \lambda D^{-1})^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}\Big(\tfrac{1}{\lambda}D + A^{-1}\Big)^{-1}A^{-1}
$$
Even if you precompute $A^{-1}$ you've just traded one inverse dependent on $D$ for another.  There are many related identities to the Woodbury identity but just from experience all of them will end up doing this, ie. trading one problematic dependence on $D$ for another.
Related to your eigendecomposition idea, this would only help you if there was a single way to diagonalize $(A+\lambda D^{-1})^{-1}$ for all possible $D$, ie. changing $D$ would not change the eigenvectors.  Unfortunately, changing $D$ will change the eigenvectors.  Probably the closest you could get would be to use the fact that $A$ is sym. psd. and define the unique sym. psd. square root, $A^{1/2}$.  You could then write
$$\Big(A + \lambda D^{-1}\Big)^{-1} = A^{1/2}\Big(I+\lambda \underbrace{A^{-1/2}D^{-1}A^{-1/2}}_{M}\Big)^{-1}A^{1/2}
$$
In order to take advantage of a structure like this you would need $M$ to be similar to $D^{-1}$.  Then, you could write $(I + \lambda M)^{-1} = V(I+\lambda D^{-1})^{-1}V^{-1}$ for the appropriate similarity transform $V$ which would be a big improvement cause now the inverse is just diagonal.  Unfortunately, no such similarity transform will exist for a general $A$.  This is because $M$ is only congruent to $D^{-1}$ not similar and congruence transformations do not preserve eigenstructure.  (They do preserve positive definiteness, however.)  You could use something like this to come up with types of $A$ for which $M$ is similar to $D^{-1}$.  A condition, for example, like $A^{1/2} = A^{-1/2}$.  This condition is called involutivity (a matrix is equal to it's own inverse).  I don't think the set of involutive symmetric positive definite matrices is very large but you could check.  Again, with this eigenvalue decomposition idea, you can play around with it, but I think you're going to find that any similarity or congruence transform you try to do on your expression is going to just move the problematic nature of $D$ around not get rid of it.
Hopefully someone can provide a better idea.
